# GNU argp: How to parse option with only long name?

Tags: c, arguments, command-line-arguments, argp

I want to use [`argp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html#Argp) in my C program to parse command line options.

One requirement is that an option does not have a short name (like `-f bar`) but only a long name (like `--foo=bar`).

My approach so far is to set the `key` field of the `argp_option` struct to `0` to make it not show a short name.

I have looked at [the provided examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp-Examples.html#Argp-Examples) and `argp.h` in detail but I can't find a means to parse an option that only has a long name in the parser function that is given to `argp`.

What I did find out is that, theoretically, in the parser I could use

```
case ARGP_KEY_ARG:
  printf("%s\n", arg);
```

to find the *value* of long options (e.g. when called with `--foo=bar`, `bar` would be printed here). However, this doesn't seem like the right approach since I don't see a simple way to actually tell which option the value belongs to. and this also shows actual command line arguments (not option values).

I'd be thankful for any tips about where I need to look. Cheers.

Comment: You can use negative numbers (e.g. `-1`) as 'short' option and then handle it in switch.

Comment: The `key` field of an option can be any `int` value. The docs state that if `isascii(key)` is true, then `key` is also a short option `-char` (`char` is the character associated with character code `key`). Technically, `isascii` ensures `0x00 <= key && key < 0x80`, so you can use any `int` value outside that range for the key. This `key` is still used as the value of the associated long option (e.g. `--foo`), so you'd handle it the same as any key/short opt. BTW, I collect all of my option keys in an `enum` as constants, so I'm not wondering what option `0x100` represents in a `switch` ;-)

Comment: @ChronoKitsune That could make an answer, 狐. Btw, why not using `-opt` as a key  (I mean, the *negative* value of what would be the short option). E.g. if `s` and `d`  are meaningful short options, use `-'s'` and `-'d'` which have both an absolute value > 0x80.

Comment: @RingØ Done. Regarding `-opt` as a key, there might not be any meaningful short option, or the short option is already in use, and adding `-opt` could get confusing. I'm a simple person, so dealing with `case 's'` and `case -'s'` could easily be confusing for me. It might be more viable when used in conjunction with the "assign the value to a mnemonic constant" idea, but that also limits you to 4 possible options using that character: `'o'`, `-'o'`, `'O'`, and `-'O'`. After that, you still have the same problem. I included an example in my answer of how one might easily remove that limitation.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Fair enough - OP might be less confused, but you seem to be knowledgeable in that segment.

Comment: OP is not confused. OP is pleased. @RingØ: However, I don't quite understand what I would pick these values as opposites *of*. Specifically, I am looking for an identifier for a long option name - that is not the opposite of any other option. Could you rephrase?

Comment: @ngmir Chrono was talking about an enum to keep keys meaningfull, depending on your options, there is a simple way to have keys > 0x80 and remain "readable" ; that is to use the negative value of a character (eg --store-disk would be -'s', etc...)

Comment: Of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ["The GNU C Library: Argp Option Vectors — Specifying Options in an Argp Parser"](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp-Option-Vectors.html):

> `int key`
>
> The integer `key` provided by the current option to the option parser.
> If `key` has a value that is a printable ASCII character (i.e.,
> `isascii (key)` is true), it also specifies a short option `-char`,
> where `char` is the ASCII character with the code `key`.

In other words, the `key` field of an option can be any `int` value, and if `isascii(key)` is nonzero, then it also specifies a short option—meaning you can use non-ASCII values (values outside the range `0x00`..`0x7F`) to avoid the short option. Despite not being a short option, the value of `key` is still used as the value of the associated long option (e.g. `--foo`), so you'd handle it the same as any key/short option.

O/T: I collect all of my option keys in an `enum` as constants, so I'm not wondering what option `0x100` represents in a `switch`, e.g. for GNU `tar`, it might be something like this for its compression options:

```
enum compress_options {
    // Archive file extension determines compression program
    COMP_FILTER_AUTO = 'a',
    // Option arg is program used to deal with compression
    COMP_FILTER_ARG = 'I',

    COMP_FILTER_BZIP2 = 'j',
    COMP_FILTER_XZ = 'J',
    COMP_FILTER_GZIP = 'z',
    COMP_FILTER_COMPRESS = 'Z',

    COMP_FILTER_LZIP = 0x100,
    COMP_FILTER_LZMA,
    COMP_FILTER_LZOP,

    // Do not use archive suffix to determine compression program.
    COMP_FILTER_NOAUTO,
};
```

Then you'd just need to ensure that the next set of options uses `0x200`, then `0x300`, etc. to avoid issues with options having the same value. If you needed, you could also use `0x100`, `0x180`, `0x200`, `0x280`, etc. (e.g. `0x100` might represent a subcommand and `0x180` might be the first option for that subcommand).

It's important to group the short options and non-short options separately. The implicitly assigned values in an `enum` depend upon the value of the last explicitly assigned value. Had I placed `COMP_FILTER_NOAUTO` immediately after `COMP_FILTER_AUTO`, the `--no-auto-compress` long option would have an associated short option `-b`, which it does not in reality.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. I really did not guess that I could just use values outside of that range and still compare them in the switch case. I am not used to this degree of "freedom" (semantic abiguity) in C programming.

Comment: Also thank you for the additional notes, I am happy for some insight. I have integrated this thought aswell.

Answer (score 1):

While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47728230/4298200) is correct, it is missing a concrete example.

Here we create two arguments, one can be used normally (`-b`) and one only via the long name (`--foo`).

```
#define ARGUMENT_BAR_SHORT 'b'
#define ARGUMENT_FOO_SHORT 0x80

static struct argp_option options[] =
{
    { "bar", ARGUMENT_BAR_SHORT, "BAR_VAL", 0, "The bar value" },
    { "foo", ARGUMENT_FOO_SHORT, "FOO_VAL", 0, "The foo value" },
}
```

And then parse it here:

```
error_t parse_opt (int option, char* arg, struct argp_state* state)
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case ARGUMENT_BAR_SHORT:
            printf("got bar: %s", arg);
            break;
        case ARGUMENT_FOO_SHORT:
            printf("got foo: %s", arg);
            break;
    }
}
```

---

For anyone who hasn't read the other answer: just use values outside the range of normal characters, which `0x80` already is. If you need more parameters, just increment this value. I also like the solution in the other answer to use an enum.

---

Also I haven't compiled this ;)